# Want button to hide content on page load then display when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

My button class is "accordion" but the content that should be hidden is displaying when the page is loaded. I want it to start as hidden and then display when clicked on.

Honestly I've tried many things and I can't remember where I started.

```js
       var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;
        
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
          acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(active) {
            this.classList.toggle("hidden");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
              panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
              panel.style.display = "block";
            }
          });
        }
```

```css
        .accordion {
          background-color: grey;
          color: #444;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 18px;
          width: 100%;
          border: 80px;
          text-align: left;
          outline: none;
          font-size: 15px;
          transition: 0.4s;
        }
        
        .active, .accordion:hover {
          background-color: grey; 
        }
        
        .panel, .button {
          padding: 80px 18px;
          display: none;
          background-color: grey;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
```

```html
    <button class="accordion" style="background-color:grey" >
        <div class="row" section-padding-80 clearfix>
        <div class="col-12 text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="800ms">
            <a href="#" class="btn alime-btn btn-2 mt-15">View More</a>
        </div>
    </div></button>
    <div class="row alime-portfolio" style="background-color:grey;">

                    <div class="container-fluid">
```

Again, I need the content to be hidden when I load the page and THEN display when the button is clicked on.

Comment: You just need to add `display:none` to your css for the relevant class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll code here an example from what you're saying, and tell me if that's what you're needing :

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("hDiv");

  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.myButton {
  background-color: grey;
}

.hidden {
  background-color: grey;
  display: none;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center wow fadeInUp">
      <a href="#" class="btn alime-btn btn-2 mt-15"  onClick="myFunction()">View More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>

    <div id="hDiv" class="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: on the right track, clicking the button again does not hide the content as before tho. Other than that that seems to be what i need

Comment: So you need it to have a toggle function over the link, got it ;)

Comment: it worked exactly as i hoped, the only issue is the display now, the original purpose of the button was to display hidden images. now all the images are shrunken in a container.

Comment: @ajortiz Now just get the container div and apply the `width` and `height` to 100% or `auto`, then the images will preserve their original size and the container will adapt to the content inside. I'd be happy if you could kindly accept my answer as the best answer and upvote it.

Comment: doesnt seem to be working with the width and height at auto or 100%

Comment: Create a new question about the issue with the images resizing inside the container div, I wish I could help you now asap, but it's midnight here and I have to sleep lol, but surely other members will be able to help you, just make sure you post the codes with a snippet or a fiddle of the part that you're trying to fix, otherwise, users might downvote your question because of the lack of information, I hope I helped you somehow !